# converting my ReactJS output to markdown

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, github-flavored-markdown

I'm busy with the first FCC Data Visualization Certification project in React and I'm a bit lost at this point.  I've managed to create the app to successfully display my input dynamically to an output div.  But now I'm stuck.  I don't quite understand the documentation I guess.  I'm struggling to alter the code to display the viewer output in markdown.  All and any help will be appreciated.

My HTML code:

```
<div id="myApp">
</div>
```

My React code:

```
class Markdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      markdown: ""
    }
  }
  toggleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      markdown: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <section className="text-center container card">
        <div className="card" id="heading">
          <h1>FCC Markdown Project</h1>
          <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="container card" id="text-display">
         {this.state.markdown}
        </div>
        <div className="container" id="text-input">
          <textarea name="md-input" rows="10" cols="90" onChange={this.toggleChange.bind(this)}></textarea>
        </div>

      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Markdown name="By: BlackBat023"/>, document.getElementById("myApp"));
```

Comment: You don't get any output whatsoever? What about any errors in console?

Comment: Hi @Chris My code does work to a point.  Whatever I type in the textarea is printed out to the Preview panel.  However I need everything in the preview panel to be converted to Markdown text.  I need help to do that.  I've tried varied methods from tutorials but that just seems to break my code & I need to reset & try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type something in the textarea, you call upon the toggleChange() method.

```
toggleChange(event){
  this.setState({
    markdown: event.target.value
  });
}
```

That method, as written your question, does not do much. It only stores what you typed in the `this.state.markdown` variable. What you need to do is process that input before you set the state.

```
toggleChange(event){
  // Process the string event.target.value that is formatted with markdown.
  // You should replace the constructs with HTML tags and then finally store it in the state.
  // processMarkdown is some function you can define (or use a third-party module) to process the input
  const processedInput = processMarkdown(event.target.value);

  this.setState({
    markdown: processedInput
  });
}
```

Comment: I know the code does exactly what I want it to do except for converting the output to markdown.  Now I know I need to process the output to markdown before I commit it to the setState() function, but I don't know how to do that.  That's what I need help with.  Been reading the documentation but that just makes my head spin :P

Comment: You can use a third-party npm module to do the markdown parsing. A quick search on the npmjs catalog ( https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=markdown ) lists many of them. Why don't you try one like `markdown-it`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it

Comment: I'm doing the project on codepen.io and I have linked to the library's cdn.  Does that count?

Comment: What I don't understand is that when I assign the var marked = require('marked'); the console says that require is undefined.

Comment: @BlackBat023 you don't have a build/bundler system. If you included the `<script>` for marked, it should already be available as a global variable.

Comment: Finally managed to get it right.  Thanks nbkhope and @Chris for your input and help.  It is greatly appreciated.